# BTEQ interactive window, need arrow-up to access command history

Tags: putty, teradata, stty

This is strange. New linux environment, accessed from my desktop via putty...

In my regular shell, I can up and down arrow to get command history. However, when I fire up BTEQ to talk to the database, I get this kind of gibberish in response to my up/down/ctrl+up/etc.

```
BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
^[OA^[OB^[[A^[[B^[OA^[OA^[[D
```

Is this something in BTEQ? I would assume more of a setting in putty or "stty" type of command in my .profile. However, since the behavior is normal until I launch BTEQ I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

BTEQ does not maintain a command history like the shell in your LINUX/UNIX environment. Therefore, using the up/down/ctl+up keys will be interpreted as input and not interpreted by the shell to navigate a command history.